# How can I implement multiple toggle functionality in ReactJS where clicking a function reveals a menu, and clicking outside the menu hides it?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

How can I implement in a page multiple toggle functionality in ReactJS where clicking a function reveals a menu, and clicking outside the menu hides it?

I did the toggle function for a single dropdown menu, but I have multiple dropdown menu to show.

I did the toggle function for a single dropdown menu, but I have multiple dropdown menu to show. For multiple toggle functionality single toggle function doesn't work, it works for all multiple dropdown at a same time for same toggle function. I need the multiple toggle functions, so that I can implement that toggle functions individually.
As like, when I click menu - the menu function will come, then again when I click category - category list will come etc, & when I click outside the menu/categorylist hide individually.

Comment: can you provide the code you're working with?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const DropdownMenu = ({ label }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const dropdownRef = useRef(null);

  const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
    if (dropdownRef.current && !dropdownRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
      setIsOpen(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, []);

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <div ref={dropdownRef}>
      <button onClick={toggleMenu}>{label}</button>
      {isOpen && (
        <div className="dropdown-menu">
          {/* Your menu content goes here */}
          <p>Dropdown content for {label}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <DropdownMenu label="Menu" />
      <DropdownMenu label="Category" />
      {/* Add more DropdownMenu components as needed */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```